# Querying MongoDB array of similar objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've to work with old MongoDB where objects in one collection are structured like this.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57fdfcc7a7c81fde38b79a3d"),
  "parameters": [
    {
      "key": "key1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "key": "key2",
      "value": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that parameters is an array of objects, which makes efficient querying difficult. There can be about 50 different objects, which all have `"key"` and `"value"` properties. Is it possible to make a query, where the query targets `"key"` and `"value"` inside one object? I've tried

```
db.collection.find({$and:[{"parameters.key":"value"}, {"parameters.value":"another value"}]})
```

but this query hits all the objects in `parameters` array.

**EDIT.** [Nikhil Jagtiani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414315/nikhil-jagtiani) found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40105578/1843163) to my original question, but actually I should be able query to target multiple objects inside parameters array. E.g. check keys and values in two different objects in parameters array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator in the aggregation framework which is perfect for such queries. A bit verbose but very efficient, you can use it as follows:

```
db.surveys.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "$and": [
            {
                "parameters.key": "key1", 
                "parameters.value": "val1"
            },
            {
                "parameters.key": "key2", 
                "parameters.value": "val2"
            }           
        ]
    }},
    {
        "$project": {
            "parameters": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$parameters",
                    "as": "item",
                    "cond": {
                        "$or": [
                            {
                                "$and" : [
                                    { "$eq": ["$$item.key", "key1"] },
                                    { "$eq": ["$$item.value", "val1"] }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "$and" : [
                                    { "$eq": ["$$item.key", "key2"] },
                                    { "$eq": ["$$item.value", "val2"] }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

You can also do this with more [set operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/) in MongoDB 2.6 without using **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**:

```
db.surveys.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "parameters.key": "key1", 
                "parameters.value": "val1"
            },
            {
                "parameters.key": "key2", 
                "parameters.value": "val2"
            }           
        ]
    }},
    { 
        "$project": {
            "parameters": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$parameters",
                        "as": "item",
                        "in": {
                             "$cond": [
                                { "$or": [
                                    {
                                        "$and" : [
                                            { "$eq": ["$$item.key", "key1"] },
                                            { "$eq": ["$$item.value", "val1"] }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$and" : [
                                            { "$eq": ["$$item.key", "key2"] },
                                            { "$eq": ["$$item.value", "val2"] }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]},
                                "$$item",
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }},
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

For a solution with MongoDB 2.4, you would need to use the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** operator unfortunately:

```
db.surveys.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "parameters.key": "key1", 
                "parameters.value": "val1"
            },
            {
                "parameters.key": "key2", 
                "parameters.value": "val2"
            }           
        ]
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$parameters" },
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "parameters.key": "key1", 
                "parameters.value": "val1"
            },
            {
                "parameters.key": "key2", 
                "parameters.value": "val2"
            }           
        ]
    }},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "parameters": { "$push": "$parameters" }            
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, your mongodb-fu seems to be very strong! Unfortunately our Mongo version is 2.4, so I think these are out of my reach :(

Comment: @JohnP I've updated the answer with a solution for version 2.4 :)

Comment: Thanks, but when I tested this query I couldn't find the document where I copied the values. Did you test this one yourself @chridam?

Comment: I just made up a bunch of documents for testing based on the schema you gave above.

Comment: Can't find anything but using just first part of your query (db.surveys.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "parameters.key": "mediator:status", 
                "parameters.value": "answered"
            },
            {
                "parameters.key": "mediator:surveyId", 
                "parameters.value": "1355202"
            }           
        ]
    }}
]);) seems to be working well. Hmmm, am I missing something...

Comment: The `$match` filter works at document level i.e. the query in `$match` filters all the documents in the collection that match the give criteria whereas at subdocument level you would then need to `$unwind` the array with the subdocuments and apply the same filter on the flattened documents.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below mongo shell aggregate query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$parameters"
    },
    {
        $match:
            {
                "parameters.key":"key1",
                "parameters.value":"value1"
            }
    }

])
```

1) Stage 1 - [Unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) : Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

2) Stage 2 - [Match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) : Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.

Without aggregation, queries will return the entire document even if one subdocument matches. **This pipeline will only return the required subdocuments.**

**Edit**: If you need to specify multiple key value pairs, what we need is $in for parameters field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$parameters"},{$match:{"parameters":{$in:[{ "key" : "key1", "value" : "value1"},{ "key" : "key2", "value" : "value2" }]}}}])
```

will match the following two pairs of key-values as subdocuments:

1)    { "key" : "key1", "value" : "value1" }

2)    { "key" : "key2", "value" : "value2" }

Comment: Thanks! This answered to my original question, but I should actually be able to do queries which targets multiple objects inside parameters array. E.g. check keys and values in two different objects in parameters array. I think in that case unwinding is not the solution?

Comment: Do you mean you multiple subdocuments match your query?

Comment: Exactly, query using $and and targeting multiple subdocuments in parameters array.

Comment: Using aggregation pipeline, if multiple subdocuments match, you will get them all as results.

Comment: I would need several subdocuments in original document match, something like this: db.surveys.aggregate({$unwind:"$parameters"},{$match:{$and:[{"parameters.key":"key1","parameters.value":"value1"}, {"parameters.key":"key2","parameters.value":"value2"}]}});

Comment: have edited my answer to accommodate the same! Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again, but this query matches if either of those subdocuments is found. Query should only return documents, where BOTH of those subdocuments are found.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make a query, where the query targets "key" and
>   "value" inside one object?

This is possible if you know which object(id) you are going to query upfront(to be given as input parameter in the find query). If that is not possible then we can try on the below approach for efficient querying.

Build an index on the parameters.key and if needed also on parameters.value. This would considerably improve the query performance.

Please see

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Comment: I have no idea about objectId's beforehand. Indexing suggestion is good, thanks.